# Laravel model event binding not called

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm adding validation to a BaseModel class which all eloquent models will eventually extend in my application.

The base class resembles:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

private $errors;
private $validator;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->validator = new BaseValidator(get_class($this));
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($model) {
         return false;
      });
    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        return false;
    });
}
```

a sample concrete that extends the base:

```
class News extends BaseModel {
protected $guarded = ['audience', 'deleted_at'];
protected $table = 'zbw_news';

//relations, scopes, etc
}
```

Whenever I create a new object through artisan tinker, the saving closure isn't being triggered (it returns `true` when it should return `false`). However, I can bind a closure directly on the model's static (instead of late static binding) and it works as expected:

```
\News::saving(function($model) { return false; });
```

Any ideas why the boot method isn't being called properly or what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: how do you know that event isn't being hit ?

Comment: Because $model->save() returns ```true```

Comment: what if you move that boot method to the child ?

Comment: already tried that, same result

Comment: How about calling `parent::construct()`?

Comment: Wow I feel like the world's biggest idiot now haha. Submit it as an answer and I'll give you the check for it.